# C# Split strings between quotes

Tags: c#, string, parsing, split

In my Resource.resx file I have a field where I put a sequence of strings like:

```
"string1" "string two" "this is the string 3"
```

My goal is to obtain a sequence of strings.

What I did until now is the following:

```
private static string[] mystrings = Resource.str.Split(null);
```

but this just split the strings based on the space character.
For the second and third strings this is a problem, so it is better to parse strings between " ".

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What about putting all different strings into a newline in your Resource.resx file and then split them at the newline character? (\n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`string.Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netcore-3.1) to remove the leading/ending quotes and then [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_) and pass `" "` as the parameter to split the strings.

```
private static string[] mystrings = Resource.str.Trim('"').Split("\" \"", StringSplitOptions.None);
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d7HaCO)